# Backup hosted repository to off-site location

Tags: version-control, backup, assembla

I am still pretty new to VCSs in general.

I have a SVN repository hosted at [assembla](http://www.assembla.com).

I know how to check out and commit to the repository. But if I wanted to actually get a backup of the repository itself to save offsite. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you using git, SVN, or Mercurial?  Git and Mercurial are backed up by cloning.

Comment: @Jacob, I am using SVN sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: @Jacob, on their site they have a `fork` option to clone the repository but it looks like it just hosts the clone too, I am not seeing a way to download a clone. Maybe there is a way I can create a clone locally via command line or tortoise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assembla provides an 'Import/Export' under the Subversion tab which allows you to get complete historical dumps of your repository.

On a repository you host yourself, you can use `svnadmin dump`